# jQuery selects change on another selects

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have this 3 selects with their options:

First:

```
<select name="website">
    <option values=""></option>
    <option value="example">example.com</option>
    <option value="holding">holding.com</option>
    <option value="apple">apple.com</option>
    <option value="morning">morning.com</option>
</select>
```

Second

```
<select name="group">
    <option values=""></option>
    <option value="marketing">marketing</option>
    <option value="sales">sales department</option>
</select>
```

Third

```
<select name="name">
    <option values=""></option>
    <option value="tom">tom</option>
    <option value="john">john</option>
    <option value="doe">doe</option>
    <option value="martin">martin</option>
</select>
```

I would like to have 3 selects to be filterable when after selecting an option from any select, the rest two shows only corresponding values with possibility to select empty option to reset this filter.

My idea is to do it like this:

```
<option class="website-example website-holding group-marketing" value="tom">tom</option>
```

so when I choose tom, on select website stays only example.com and holding.com and on select group stayl only marketingand so on.

So option from one select has values from another select in their class for ex + on select first option has value "" for reset filtering.

Do you have any idea how to solve it or how to solve it better?

Comment: I think you can disable the other choices when one is selected. Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: what you had tried so far ?

Comment: how do you know which belongs to which

Comment: You also need to have some association or relation between the selected option from one another, to toggle(hide/show) options depending on selected options

Comment: @madalinivascu I know how is it conected. I edit my question and I would like to have only small piece of jquery, because definition of classes is easy.

Comment: @Jean-maximeBouloc It would be nice to disable it dynamically not one by one ;) And that is my question. How to load all possibilities of values and then disable on change and select from any select.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the rel attr against your corresponding item to be displayed through the click function

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
$("select[name='website']").on('change', function() {
    if ('example' === $("option:selected", this).val()) {
        $("option[value='marketing']").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

And if you can, make it as dynamically as possible

Comment: that is what I am asking how to do it dynamically ;)

Comment: With an array with all option to be disable and loop through it